# Keeping an object or creating new one when require. Which is better?

Tags: ios, object, memory-management

I am confused that which approach of the below is better?

1. Create and keep an object in memory.
2. Create an object when needed and destroy it after that.

There may be situations when we may need same object multiple time. Like side menu or some other modal class. 
We can either create singleton object and keep the object in memory. This approach has a downfall that we may not using that object so frequently but it is still in memory.

Second approach is to create an object when require and than destroy it. This approach will save memory but consume object creation and destroy process.

I think that 1st approach is better as it will be good to keep a object which may need multiple time rather than creating it every time but still want to clear thing in more detail that which approach is best and why.

Thanks

Comment: I'd say: Don't optimize prematurely. Just write the program. If there is a performance or memory issue in real life later on, then you can worry about whether changing this sort of thing might make a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the second approach is better, as by using this the object will not be unnecessary in the memory. when ever you want to use is create it and destroy it once you have done with object.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is created easily, and cost less, lazy-load style, the second way, is better. This is recommended way in most cases.

Whereas, if the object is create cost much, and used frequently, the first way is better.